# Converting webform code to winforms application

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, webforms

I am trying to create a broken linkchecker application and have aquired some webforms working code that accepts a url and digs through the pages relating to that url, checking all the links and returning a ok or invalid link message. My problem is that the webforms application has a line that uses sessions to return the data, would anyone know what I can do to replace this line to get it working using winforms:

```
   public WebSpider WebSpider
        {
            get { return (WebSpider)(Session["webSpider"] ?? (Session["webSpider"] = new WebSpider())); }
        }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need sessions in a windows forms application...there's no "sessions" as we know it in windows forms. Just use local variables if you want to maintain state within a single form or use a singleton object that can be shared across the application and multiple form instances